# Cryptography error with C

Tags: c, string, cryptography

I am trying to create a program that can modify a text according to the user key. It seems to work well, until I input something and it adds extra things.

For example, if I add the word hello and a key of 3, it says khoor plus some extra weird characters. Can you tell me please what is the problem? Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXSIZE 100

void encrypt(senTence[], int key);

int main(void)
{
    int userKey;
    char sentence[MAXSIZE];

    printf("Input the text that you want to encrypt:\n> ");
    fgets(sentence, 99, stdin);

   // printf("\nThe string that you wrote is:\n%s\n\n", sentence);

    printf("Input the key:\n");
    scanf("%d", &userKey);

    //printf("\nThe key that you selected is: %d\n\n", userKey);

    encrypt(sentence, userKey);

    return 0;
}

void encrypt(const char senTence[], int key)
{
    int i = 0;
    char q[MAXSIZE];

    for(i = 0; senTence[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if( ( isupper(senTence[i]) ) || ( islower(senTence[i]) ) )
        {
            q[i] = senTence[i] + (char)key;
        }
        else
        {
            q[i] = (senTence[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("%s", q);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't terminate the result string `q` in `encrypt()`.
Add the following line before `printf()`.

```
q[i] = '\0';
```

Another way is initialize `q` to all-zero:

```
char q[MAXSIZE] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to null terminate your array `q`, so using as a string will not be possible.

After you have performed the required operation on all the elements of the `senTence` and stored it to `q`, you need to null terminate `q`.

Use

```
q[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", q);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code, was giving a few warnings and an error, related to the function prototype. I fixed that and it is working fine now!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXSIZE 100

void encrypt(const char senTence[], int key);

int main(void)
{
    int userKey;
    char sentence[MAXSIZE];

    printf("Input the text that you want to encrypt:\n> ");
    fgets(sentence, 99, stdin);

   // printf("\nThe string that you wrote is:\n%s\n\n", sentence);

    printf("Input the key:\n");
    scanf("%d", &userKey);

    //printf("\nThe key that you selected is: %d\n\n", userKey);

    encrypt(sentence, userKey);

    return 0;
}

void encrypt(const char senTence[], int key)
{
    int i = 0;
    char q[MAXSIZE];

    for(i = 0; senTence[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if( ( isupper(senTence[i]) ) || ( islower(senTence[i]) ) )
        {
            q[i] = senTence[i] + (char)key;
        }
        else
        {
            q[i] = (senTence[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("%s", q);

}
```